# MacOS/OSX Webview not opening external links

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

I have a basic `WebView` loading and external webpage.

External links will not load/do anything when clicked (*within the webview is expected*).  Internal links load as expected

- App transport security settings in `plist` set to "Allow arbitrary loads"
- Ive looked at WebPolicyDelegate: https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/webpolicydelegate?language=objc As i ithought perhaps i needed to set a policy however this only seems to apply when loading extrnal links in separate browser

What box have I not ticked/allowed/missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define these two methods (one from WebPolicyDelegate and the other from WebUIDelegate) to open every page from every domain, including the ones that should open in different tabs or windows (it will open in the same WebView though).

In my case I've created a WebView subclass (VMWebView) to handle that for me:

```
@implementation VMWebView

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.UIDelegate = self;
    self.policyDelegate = self;
}

-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request
         frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
{
    // Opens everything
    [listener use];
}

-(WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    // Opens new tab/window pages 
    return sender;
}

@end
```

Check if that works for you.